# How to add extra fields in RxJS observable and wait for it to complete?

Tags: javascript, rxjs

I have an observable that returns `items`, I need only one specific item and I want to add some extra fields to it from a http request which is also observable. Code below is how I'm trying to achieve that but it doesn't work. I need all observables to complete to get the full item data in `ngOnInit`. What am I missing?

```js
ngOnInit() {
    myItemsObservable$(this.store, items, items.data)
        .map(items => items.find(
            item => {
                return item.id === id
            }
        ))
        .concatMap(item => {
            return this.apiService.get(`/items/${item.id}/extradata`).map(extra => ({
                ...item,
                extra
            }))
        })
        .subscribe(item => {
            // I expect item to have extra fields here.
            this.item = item
        })

        // this.item here should already be complete.
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's look at a simplified  version of your code:

```js
1  function ngOnInit() {
2    myItemsObservable$().subscribe(item => this.item = item);
3    console.log(this.item); // undefined
4  }
```

You are essentially calling two functions that get executed immediately one after the other.

Line 2 creates a subscription object which initiates the flow of data inside the observable.  But... execution is not paused after line 2.  So then, Line 3 is executed, before the asynchronous tasks within the observable have been completed. This is why `this.item` is still `undefined` on line 3.

Hopefully, you can see why your comment is not correct:

```
// this.item here should already be complete.
```

You are passing a function (`item => this.item = item`) to the `subscribe()` method that handles emissions from the observable when they occur.  This is the place in your code where you actually have the emitted value.

So, if we move the `console.log()` inside the subscribe, `this.item` would no longer be undefined:

```js
1  function ngOnInit() {
2    myItemsObservable$().subscribe(item => {
3      this.item = item;
4      console.log(this.item); // not undefined :-)
5    });
6  }
```

To address the two parts of your question:

> How to add extra fields in RxJS observable

You are already doing this.  You've used the `map` and `concatMap` operators to modify values emitted by the source observable into your desired value.

> ...and wait for it to complete?

Well, you don't "wait" for it per se.  With RxJS, you are defining the behavior of how the data flows.  The only place you have access to the actual data is inside the subscribe.

But... instead of subscribing, then copying the data from the observable to another variable, you can simply reference the observable directly in other parts of your code.

Let's break your code up into a few different parts so it's easier to see how we can reference different observable sources without subscribing:

```js
id$ = this.route.paramMap.pipe(  // This could come from a form control input
    params => params.get('id')   // or some other observable source.
);

allItems$ = myItemsObservable$(this.store, items, items.data);

getItem$(id) {
  return this.allItems$.pipe(
    map(items => items.find(i.id === id))
  );
}

getExtraData$(id) {
  return this.apiService.get(`/items/${id}/extradata`);
}

item$ = this.id$.pipe(
    switchMap(id => getItem$(id)),
    switchMap(item => this.getExtraData(item.id).pipe(
      map(extra => ({ ...item, ...extra }))
    ))
  );
}
```

See how the definition of `item$` starts with the `id$`? This means that whenever `id$` emits a new value, `item$` will automatically call `getItem$()`, then `getExtraData()` then emit this new item.  We didn't need to subscribe to make that happen.

We can simply define an observable to start with another observable then `.pipe()` the emissions and transform them to suit our needs.

We've essentially designed an observable that will emit any time that item in the store changes, or whenever our selected `id$` emits a new value.  In a sense, we've built up `item$` to represent our `item` and it will always be up to date, including having its "extra data" appended.  This is very powerful.  Now we can just use it.

Notice the definition of `item$` doesn't need to be in `ngOnInit`; it can actually go directly on your component.

It's true we could subscribe in our component... but we can usually just use the [`AsyncPipe`](https://angular.io/guide/observables-in-angular#async-pipe) in the template:

```
<div *ngIf="item$ | async as item">
  <h1>{{ item.name }}</h1>
  <ul>
    <li>{{ item.description  }}</li>
    <li>{{ item.someProperty }}</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

If you find yourself often subscribing in your component, only to copy the data to a local variable, just to be consumed by your template; I would encourage you to pause and ask yourself it its really necessary.  Most of the time you can define an observable that emits exactly the data your view needs without ever needing to subscribe.

RxJS provides many operators and static functions that make it easy to create observables with a variety of common behaviors.

Comment: This is a great answer. I tried to do something similar with async but was confused because this.item was available in the init without me adding the additional request. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Are you using an old version of angular and rxjs? In the current way, map is not a method of observables.

Instead, I think you would be looking for something like this;

```
function ngOnInit() {
  myItemsObservable$(this.store, items, items.data)
    .pipe(
      filter(item => item.id === id), // assuming your observable emits each item separately. Otherwise, use your map statement above.
      take(1), // do you need this? I'm guessing you wouldn't.
      concatMap(item => this.apiService.get(`,/items/${item.id}/extradata`)
        .pipe(
          map(extra => Object.assign({}, item, {extra})) // if I understand what you are wanting here, otherwise replace "{extra}" with "extra", or go back to your original notation
        )
      )
    )
    .subscribe(
      item => {
          // I expect item to have extra fields here.
          this.item = item
      }
    )
  // this.item here should already be complete.
}
```

Comment: this.item after observable code is still undefined, so it still doesn't wait for observable to complete