# Wait observable to complete in each array before returning the value

Tags: angular, rxjs

I am calling an observable on each element in the array to get user information and return those array with information from observable but I don't see any update from the array before it returns.

```
getUserInfo(){
 let userCompleteInfo = this.userInfo.map(user=>{
   let fullName: string;
   if(user.userId){
     this.getUserFullName(user.userId).pipe(
     tap(userFName=>{
        fullName = userFName
       })
     ).subscribe();
   }
   return {
      id: user.userId,
      fullName: fullName
    }
 })

 return userCompleteInfo;
}
```

The code above is not returning the fullName value from observable, even the observable is producing correct value.

Comment: Your problem is similar to the one explained in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66872283/1858357).  Instead of attempting to return resolved value, you should return an observable like @Havald suggests below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well as you already pointed out you return the fullName before the function in the observable sets the fullName.

You can use the [combineLatest](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/combination/combinelatest) operator from rxjs to wait for all the the observable to get the fullName and return an observable from the function:

```
 public getUserInfo(): Observable<{id: string, fullName: string}[]>{
   
  return combineLatest(this.userInfo.map(user => 
    this.getUserFullName(user.userId).pipe(
     map(fullname => ({id: user.userId, fullName: fullName}))
    )
  ));
}
```

The combineLatest operator from rxjs waits for all the observable in the parameter array and then returns its value as an array of all the results from the passed in observable.