# Return an observable array with outer response properties and inner response properties Angular

Tags: angular, rxjs, rxjs-observables, rxjs-pipeable-operators

How to make an api call and from it's response which is an array, make API calls with data from each array element and return an observable array Angular

for ex,

```
queryThatReturnsArray().pipe(
    map((v) => {
        anotherQuery(v.id).pipe(
            map(res => {
                return {
                    name: v.name,
                    prop2: res.prop
                }
            })  
        )
    })
)
```

So the final outcome has to be an observable array with each array object having certain properties from the outer API response as well as some properties from inner API response

Comment: Maybe [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66872283/1858357) will help you.

Answer (score 1):

First make the API call and get the array, then using map, create an observable using `of` for each element, then run the other api call, merge the two requests using `map`, finally, all the apis are execute parallely to give the output inside the subscribe!

```
queryThatReturnsArray().pipe(
    switchMap((array) => {
        const arrayData = array.map(varr => of(varr).pipe(
            switchMap((v) => {
                return anotherQuery(v.id).pipe(
                    map((res) => ({
                        name: v.name,
                        prop2: res.prop
                    }))
                )
            })
        ))
        return forkJoin(arrayData);
    })
).subscribe(output => console.log(output))
```

Answer (score 1):

Map the array of values to an array of observables and pass the array of observables to a suitable [combination operator](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/combination) e.g. `forkJoin`.

The original observable can be mapped to the combined observable using [switchMap](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/transformation/switchmap).

```js
queryThatReturnsArray().pipe(
  switchMap(array => forkJoin(
      array.map(v => anotherQuery(v.id)
    )
  ))
);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
queryThatReturnsArray().pipe(
  switchMap(outerArrayResponse => forkJoin(outerArrayResponse.map(
    outerArrayElement => innerQuery(outerArrayElement.id).pipe(
      map(innerElement => {
        return {
            name: outerArrayElement.name,
            prop2: innerElement.prop
        };
      }),
    );
  ))),
).subscribe(output => console.log(output));
```

Answer (score 0):

there is no need to create an inner observable from the array. It is easier to `flatMap` the first array, transform individual elements, and collect the array at the end.

```
queryThatReturnsArray().pipe(
  mergeMap((allValues) => allValues),
  mergeMap((v) => anotherQuery(v.id).pipe(
    map((res) => ({ name: v.name, prop2: res.prop })),
  ),
  toArray(),
)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
let sources: Observable<any>[] = [];
  this._findQuote
    .getQuote(masterKey)
    .pipe(
      switchMap((res: any) => {
        sources.push(
          new Observable((obs) => {
            obs.next(res);
            obs.complete();
          })
        );
        res.keyItemList.forEach((obj: any) => {
          
            sources.push(
              this._productCatelogueService.getByProductNo(
                Number(obj.productNo)
              )
            );
          
        });
        return forkJoin(sources);
      })
    )
    .subscribe(
      (response: any) => {
        console.log(response);
      },
      (error) => {
  }
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).